# joomla 2.5: ajax login, check if username and password is correct

Tags: php, ajax, hash, joomla

Im developing a AJAX login form for **joomla 2.5**. It's all working fine, last thing I need to achieve is the password checking. The password is being received with this piece of code:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

in the database the password looks like this

```
0c7aca777a2fec9c962a0e3938b8cb0f:7Zv9CyiSiIzFYDS7RtqrzsxuenjmmOgi
```

and this is the query (dont mind the safety for now)

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM q4jli_users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
```

the second part of the hashed password is a random salt, so I think this cannot be checked, maybe I should only check the first part of the hashed password.

Any ideas? Assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Joomla API Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin).  If you don't find what you need there, take a look at the default joomla authenticatin plugin at `plugins\authentication\joomla\joomla.php`, some of the other authentication plugins that are installed with Joomla.

And finally, this question: [Custom PHP function to verify correct password in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015106/custom-php-function-to-verify-correct-password-in-joomla), might assist as well.